# Go to certain part of page in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

Is it possible to skip to a certain part of a page in jquery, for example I am on index.html and I want to go to the middle of the page on page2.html how do i make a link that does that? Thanks in advance for your answers. :)

P.S. I have to use jquery because thats what im using for the whole site so the whole #location-on-page will NOT work :) Thanks

Snippet 1:

```
<a href="page.html#1"><img src="image_location/1.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
```

Snippet 2:

```
<a href="image_folder/1.jpg"><img src="image_folder/1.jpg"><br>
Description
<a name="1"></a>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML for the links, and if you're using jQuery/JavaScript to trigger the navigation show the code for that too. jQuery should have nothing to do with how linking to a particular anchor tag works with the # syntax, so you must be doing something else in your code to break it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with Javascript alternatives to go to an anchor  rather then using href links.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need to go to a specific anchor via Javascript and not by clicking an anchor tag on the page then use

`location.href = "#anchor";`

jQuery isn't needed in this case but if you wanted too, you could simply create your own custom jQuery function

```
$.fn.gotoAnchor = function(anchor) {
    location.href = this.selector;
}

$('#1').gotoAnchor();

// This way would also allow going to another pages anchors like so
$('page2.html#1').gotoAnchor();
```

or

```
$.fn.gotoAnchor = function(anchor) {
    location.href = '#' + this.selector;
}

$('1').gotoAnchor();
```

Depending on if you want to have to specifiy the anchor character `#` in your selector.

Comment: Awesome, but i have a very noooobish question, which page do i put the code on?

Comment: Whatever page you want the functionality on.  Ideally you'd have your own Javascript file with your custom code in it on which you include on your pages via `<script type="text/javascript" src="/myscript.js">` tag, then it'll be available on any page you include the script on.  Just make sure you include your script after jQuery because it's extending upon the functionality of jQuery so the jQuery object must be available.

Comment: Quick Question, I have like 50 links on some pages, will one of the codes you wrote make all the anchors work?

Comment: As long as your links have anchors name="anchor_name" and you include the script on the page then sure.

Answer (score 7):

You have to put an anchor in. No need for jQuery!

On page 2 - where you want it to jump to.

```
<a name="myanchor"></a>
```

On page 1.

```
<a href="page2.html#myanchor">Link</a>
```

Comment: No I am using jquery for my whole website and #certain-location-on-page doesn't work with jquery! Thats what I was using previously but it wont work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That is a feature of HTML, not jQuery, so will work with both.

On page2.html you need to include a named anchor tag where you want the page to go to...

```
<a name="half-way">&nbsp;</a>
```

Then in index.html, you can use an anchor tag that points there...

```
<a href="page2.html#half-way">This should get you half way..!</a>
```

You could use jQuery to generate these tags if you wanted to.

Comment: Yes it does. You must be doing something else to break it. Please show your code.